# Do journals with double-blind review allow submission with some of the references are yet to appear but already accepted in another journal?

Tags: journals

There are journals which employ double-blind review. Suppose I want to submit in such journals but my paper to be submitted depends on another paper of mine which was already accepted in another journal but does not appear in its issue. In my view, this might reveal my identity and hence defeats the purpose of the double-blind review? Do these kind of journals allow such submissions? I read the authors' guidelines but seems this particular concern is not stated.

Answer (score 1):

It's allowed. Ask the editor how they'd like you to blind this particular reference.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @RoboKaren, I think it answers the question as well as it can be answered. Of course the submission is "allowed", but every journal with double-blind submission will have different standards for blinding this kind of reference. I don't think it's a big deal, and it should be easy to get a response from an editor on how best to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to handle a reference of this type is to list its authors as "blinded" (or similar verbiage). This makes it clear that it is a legitimate article, but that it cannot currently be fully revealed for the sake of blinding.

Comment: This is probably not the ideal place for such comments, but: it seems to me that "double-blind" refereeing could lead to all kinds of awkward progress.  Just two examples: (i) if the work which is being used is "blinded", then the referee cannot check it.  This means that *at best* the work can be certified correct modulo certain black boxes and thus seems like a good way to propagate errors.  In practice, many errors occur "between the two papers", i.e., in the application of paper 1 to paper 2.

Comment: (ii) If the used work is being blinded, how on earth can the referee assess the *marginal* novelty/value of Paper 2 with respect to Paper 1?  A quite common cause of rejection of papers is "This is too similar to your last paper to be published in a journal of this quality."  This concern seems to go out the window with double-blinding.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Both of these are good arguments against double-blinding.  Still, many venues use it, and one must deal with their requirements.

Comment: "[A]nd one must deal with their requirements".  Your sentence ended a little early: you left off "...or risk suffering the consequences."  One could equally well say "There are good arguments that Elsevier works against the interests of academics.  Still, some of their journals are among the top ones in a given academic field, so one must deal with whatever they require."  Again the sentence ends too early.  If one happened to feel sufficiently strongly that something is not a good practice: don't do it, but be prepared for the consequences.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark If you feel so strongly about double-blinding, sure.  Personally, I think there are also a lot of good arguments *for* double-blinding, and don't find much reason to fight strongly for or against it.

Comment: I must confess that I am making an, ahem, purely academic argument.  Double-blinding would simply make no sense in any field with a thriving preprint culture, such as mine.  So indeed we don't have it in my field.  Crusade accomplished.  (The real crusade is: why do some fields treat academic manuscripts as being on double-secret lockdown??) Perhaps I should also admit that I do business with Elsevier!  My point is that participation in any voluntary activity connotes a certain level of approval.  It is good to remind people of that every now and then.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark, there have been [studies](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/mckinley/notes/blind.html) done in CS that show that double-blind review removes bias (which is/was a big problem) and improves quality. Most venues have ways of dealing with your objections (often breaking the blinding after a first round of review in order to determine the answers to your questions).